# Finding x,y coordinates from a pixel - python

Tags: python, coordinates, pixel, point

I have a raster file (300 by 300) representing a shop point and houses. The shop has the value 1 in the text file and the houses the numbers 10 - 250. I have open this text file into spyder but I don't know how to find the location point of the shop and houses.

Comment: Add more details and code to show what you have done so far

Answer (score 1):

Raster cells have a `cell size`. So if you have a raster file with x-rows and y-cols, you just need to determine either of the following:

`min/max` coordinate in the X and Y directions

`lower-left x/y` coordinate pair

Once you find either of these, simple calculations determine what the center coordinate is based on the index of the `1` in the raster file.